# iOS css position bug (position: relative not applying on mobile)

Tags: html, ios, css, cross-browser

I have a `div` which requires `position: relative` in order to center the `div` vertically. It works fine on computer browsers, but on some iOS devices it seems as if the `position: relative` is not being applied. Thus, the `div` is cut off at the top by 50% as it has styling: `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
<div id="parent" style="position: relative">
    <div id="child" style="position: relative; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
<div>
```

Is there something about how my code is set up that causes it to not work **specifically** on just some iOS devices (works on iPhone 8 but not 6)?

Comment: I thought about that, but then wouldn't the div be 50% further down the page not 50% pushed upward? But what would be the proper cross-browser version of `transform: translateY` ?

Comment: Just tried with the vendor prefixes and same result. The `transform: translateY(-50%)` is definitely being applied as, again, it is cut off at the top because that -50% is applied but the `top:50%` is not applied (I think because position relative is not applied)